# Expand the function $\ln(27+x^3)$ as a power series at x=0

Tags: calculus

Expand the function $\ln(27+x^3)$ as a power series at $x=0$

A) What is the radius of convergence of this series?

B) What is the coeﬃcient of $x^{12}$ in this series?

Not sure what to do?

Comment: HINT: $\ln(27+x^3)=\ln27+\ln\left(1+\left(\frac x3\right)^3\right)$

Comment: You will also have to use the power series expansion $\ln(1+x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^k}{k}$, with radius of convergence $1$.

Comment: Comment(s) $\equiv$ answer.

Comment: so ∑∞ n=1 ((-1)^k(26+x^3)^K)/K right?

Comment: Not exactly — the constant term $\ln 27 = 3\ln 3$ stays outside, it does not go into the series (hte whole point was to "put it out"). 

$$\ln(27+x^3) = \ln 27 + \ln\left(1+\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^3\right) =  3\ln 3 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^{3k}}{3^{3k}k}$$ as long as $|x| < 3$ (from $|(x/3)^3| < 1$, because of the original radius of convergence). You substitute "$x$" in the power series for $\ln(1+x)$ by the actual thing here -- that is, $(x/3)^3$ (which then must satisfy $|(x/3)^3| < 1$ for everything to be defined).

Comment: So the answer is 3 for the radius of convergence?

Comment: If it is a homework, given all that's above, you should try to find and convince yourself of the answer by yourself, now.

Comment: Ok so how do i go about finding x^12 coefficent?

Answer (score 3):

The question has been answered in the comments by @lab bhattacharjee, et al.